Transforming request query with '%' character in parameter
My application is using the following request's handling chain:
Nginx Server -> Nest.js HTTP controller -> Nest.js service and PostgreSQL connection.
It supports sending parameters for filtering results in the following way: the filter parameter is sent, which is an array of objects:
hostname.com/posts?filter=[{"property":"title","operator":"=","value":"RAW234"}]
This construction with operator property is further transformed into the SQL query like:
WHERE title is 'RAW234' . I would like to allow users to send 'ILIKE' operator to filter result with wildcard. My filter parameter will be: filter=[{"property":"title","operator":"ilike","value":"%234"}] and here I got a problem - my app is not able to parse filter query parameter with JSON.parse() method further in the request processing chain.
I have two different cases: Proper processing chain and Chain with error
Proper chain

Frontend app sends HTTP GET request:
hostname.com/posts?filter=[{"property":"title","operator":"ilike","value":"RAW234"}]
Nginx receives as GET hostname.com/posts?filter=[{%22property%22:%22title%22,%22operator%22:%22ilike%22,%22value%22:%22RAW234%22}]
Nginx transmit (I don't control this process for now but I am able to change any Nginx setting) it to Nest HTTP controller GET handler
Nest HTTP controller receives this request as hostname.com/posts?filter=[{"property":"title","operator":"like","value":"RAW234"}]
I can parse it with JSON.parse(request.query.filter) method

Chain with error

Frontend app sends HTTP GET request:
hostname.com/posts?filter=[{"property":"title","operator":"ilike","value":"RAW234%"}] - value is RAW234% - with % symbol in the end
Nginx receives as GET hostname.com/posts?filter=[{%22property%22:%22title%22,%22operator%22:%22ilike%22,%22value%22:%22RAW234%%22}]
Nginx transmit (I don't control this process for now but I am able to change any Nginx setting) it to Nest HTTP controller GET handler
Nest HTTP controller receives this request as hostname.com/posts?filter=[{%22property%22:%22title%22,%22operator%22:%22=%22,%22value%22:%22RAW%%22}]
I can not parse it with JSON.parse(request.query.filter) method - filter is not a valid JSON-string now

I am not encode-decode anything manually now in both cases.
My Nginx config for this route looks like:
 location ~ ^/posts/?(.*) {
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://$post_microservice_backend/posts/$1$is_args$args;
    }


Is it possible to receive filter parameter as [{"property":"title","operator":"ilike","value":"RAW%"}] when I use % symbol - at STEP 4?
Maybe it is my Nginx settings issue?
I tried to use decodeURIComponent but it can not parse invalid string with URI malformed error. Of course, I can use regular expressions and similar methods to transform a string to get a valid value, but maybe I can change some setting so that it works right away?


I see you are building the URL manually, in that case "%" symbol should also be url-encoded, not just "%" but "%25", some details in this so question


Your example chains do not match up, so it is hard to say what is going on. 2) This really has nothing to do with Postgres, I am removing that tag.


@AdrianKlaver Oh, thanks for that notice - I add two equal cases to explain.
